# module 'discord' has no attribute 'AutoShardedBot'

Tags: python, discord.py

***CODE***

I need help and errors keep on popping up.

```
bot = discord.AutoShardedBot(shard_count=20, intents=discord.Intents.all())
times = 0
ids = []
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
```

***ERORR***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/container/bot.py", line 30, in <module>
        bot = discord.AutoShardedBot(shard_count=20, intents=discord.Intents.default())
    AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'AutoShardedBot'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a better look at the error next time. (module 'discord' has no attribute 'AutoShardedBot') you have probably made a typo.

Fixed code:

```
bot = discord.AutoShardedClient(shard_count=20, intents=discord.Intents.all())
times = 0
ids = []
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
```

Comment: Hi there it still doesn’t work. With your code, what else could I do

Comment: Hello! Please add the whole file to the question so I could understand more.